# Should we serialize std::chrono::duration class or is it P.O.D. (Plain Old Data) and no serialization is needed?

Tags: c++, type-traits

I am having an argument with my friend about *P.O.D* types in C++. The whole fuss is about whether we shall serialize the struct below or not. And we should serialize if the struct is not a *P.O.D.* (Plan Old Data).

He says, that if official standard does not state, that **std::chrono::duration** has to be *P.O.D.* than it's up to the implementation and we are safer when we always serialize it.

However I have wrote a little code [gist](http://cpp.sh/8vk5a) that proves it is trivial, has standard layout and is thus *P.O.D.*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

struct myStruct
{
    std::chrono::seconds timeSec;
};

int main () {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "is_pod<std::chrono::seconds> = "
              << std::is_pod<std::chrono::seconds>() << std::endl
              << "is_pod<myStruct> = " << std::is_pod<myStruct>() << std::endl;


    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "is_trivial<std::chrono::seconds> = "
              << std::is_trivial<std::chrono::seconds>() << std::endl
              << "is_is_standard_layout<std::chrono::seconds> = "
              << std::is_standard_layout<std::chrono::seconds>() << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "is_trivial<myStruct> = "
              << std::is_trivial<myStruct>() << std::endl
              << "is_is_standard_layout<myStruct> = "
              << std::is_standard_layout<myStruct>() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You could specialize for [`std::is_trivially_copyable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable) and let the compiler handle that concern for you.

Comment: Note that [`std::is_pod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pod) is expected to be deprecated in c++20. The POD type requirement is being replaced by more specific type requirements.

Comment: How does being a POD affect whether you "shall" serialise it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code "proves" only one thing: that the implementation you ran it on implemented `duration` such that it is trivially copyable and standard layout. Nothing in the standard *requires* it to be so, so any other implementation (including later versions of the *same* library) can freely change the rules.

Now, you can do some `if constexpr`/`enable_if` or similar gymnastics, so that if an implementation provides trivial copyability, you use that ability rather than "serializing" it. But you can't *assume* that this will always be the case (unless you are working in an environment where you know you will always use a particular library); you can merely take advantage of it where available.